# Mouseenter, mouseleave in epmty DIV. Change a color and remove it

Tags: javascript, html, background-color, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have this simple code in html with css and js...But its not running.
I'm a beginner in JS and I can't find out why my mouseover(I even tried mouseenter) is not working. Can somebody explain it to me? 
Also i need to do mouse-leave so when the user leaves the box red color is gone.
I know guys this is very simple but I can't solve it :(

Thanks

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div></div>

  <script>
    var box = document.querySelector('div')[0];
    if (box) {
      box.addEventListener('mouseover', colorin);
    }

    function colorin(e) {
      e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached the working code below, you need to change `e.style.backgroundColor = "red";` to `e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";` Without the .target there isn't an DOM element to change. Also, as you mentioned you need to have a mouseout event which reverts the color back to white when the user is no longer focused on that div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>

        div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>

        <script>
            var box = document.querySelector('div');
            if(box) {
                box.addEventListener('mouseenter', colorin);
                box.addEventListener('mouseout', colorout);

            }

            function colorin(e) {
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }

            function colorout(e) {
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: oh man...Really ty... I completly forgot to add target even tho I added it before that and something went wrong so i deleted and forgot. Ty very much